# Oracle search for patterns

Tags: oracle

So, we have a CLOB that is actually a JSON string.   The pattern is somewhat like this:

```
{"section_1":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":"<p style=
.
.
.
"section_27":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":""},
"section_28":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":""},
.
.
```

You get the idea.   What I need to do is find the LAST "section_#", as I need to append some text into it.

I'm sure that this can be done via some REGEXP_LIKE or something, just not sure how to approach this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this as starting point, it will give you the highest # of the "section_#"

```
with data(js) as (
    select q'~{"section_1":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":""},
    "section_27":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":""},
    "section_28":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":""}}~' from dual
)
select max(to_number(regexp_substr(PATH,'\d++'))) AS latest_section
from json_table(
  (select json_dataguide(js) from data)
  , '$[*]?(@."o:path" eq_regex ".*section_\\d+")'
    columns(
      path varchar2(128) path '$."o:path"'
    )
);
```

from here you should be able to get the section you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In case the latest section is not the one with the greatest # but really the one at latest position you can use the "for ordinality" functionality:

```
with data(js) as (
    select q'~{
    "section_1":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":"1"},
    "section_27":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":"27"},
    "section_28":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":"28"}
    }~' from dual
),
sections(rn, section_path) as (
    select rn, path 
    from json_table(
        (select json_dataguide(js) from data), 
        '$[*]?(@."o:path" eq_regex ".*section_\\d+")'
        columns(
            rn for ordinality,
            path varchar2(128) path '$."o:path"'
        )
    )
)
select section_path, section, t.rn
from data,
json_table(
    js,
    '$.*'
    columns (
        rn for ordinality,
        section json path '$'
    )
) t
join sections s on s.rn = t.rn
where t.rn = (select max(rn) from sections)
;
```